# $U_1\oplus U_2$ decomposable into $I\oplus U$ and 1-qubit gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

### TL;DR

Let $U_1, U_2, U$ be arbitrary 1-qubit quantum gates.
Can 2-qubit gates of the form $U_1\oplus U_2$ always be decomposed into a combination of controlled gates ($I\oplus U$) and single qubit gates?

### Context

The paper [Optimal local implementation of non-local quantum gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005101) presents the following quantum circuit to teleport a controlled gate.

[image: gate teleportation circuit]

This circuit does not only work for controlled gates of the form $\left[\begin{matrix}I & 0 \\ 0 & U\end{matrix}\right]$, but also for 2-qubit gates of the from $\left[\begin{matrix}U_1 & 0 \\ 0 & U_2\end{matrix}\right]$.

I'm not sure if that observation allows for the teleportation of other 2-qubit gates than achievable with only 1 controlled gate plus single qubit operations.
Hence my question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A \oplus B$ translates to:

```
if q1:
    apply B to q2
else:
    apply A to q2
```

which is equivalent to

```
if q1:
    apply A to q2
    apply A† to q2
    apply B to q2
else:
    apply A to q2
```

which is equivalent to:

```
apply A to q2
if q1:
    apply A† to q2
    apply B to q2
```

which is equivalent to:

```
apply A to q2
if q1:
    apply (B·A†) to q2
```

which is a single qubit gate followed by a controlled gate, which is of the form you asked for.

Comment: This is very interesting! I had never thought about it like this!

Comment: Your gates are applied from right to left?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch That's unfortunately the standard ordering of matrix multiplication, not my choice.

Comment: I'd say the problem is that we use column vectors, not matrix multiplication ;) ... but either way, in pseudocode one could just as well apply gates from left to right (indeed, this is way I assumed until the last line). Then again, just today I saw Jeongwan Haah draw a circuit from right to left ... :-o

Answer (score 3):

*Any* two-qubit gate can be decomposed in terms of one-qubit gates and CNOTs (or some other two-qubit gate). Thus, this is in particular true for the special subclass you ask about.

Answer (score 2):

The main mathematical observation is that you can decompose direct sums as sums of tensor products as
$$A\oplus B = \mathbb{P}_0 \otimes A + \mathbb{P}_1\otimes B,
\qquad \mathbb{P}_i\equiv |i\rangle\!\langle i|.$$
The rest is a simple algebraic manipulation:
$$A\oplus B = (I\otimes A)(\mathbb{P}_0\otimes I + \mathbb{P}_1\otimes (A^\dagger B))
= (I\otimes A)[I\oplus (A^\dagger B)]
\\
= [I\oplus (BA^\dagger)](I\otimes A),$$
and the observation that $(I\otimes A)$ is a one-qubit gate and $I\oplus (A^\dagger B)$ is the controlled gate.

Comment: What is the added value of the decomposition into projectors, rather than going right away from the 1st to the 3rs step in the equation?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I guess to see more clearly why $A\oplus B$ becomes $I\otimes A$ etc? It's just another way to write the direct sum decomposition without having to write the matrices

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{pmatrix} U_1\\& U_2 \end{pmatrix}
=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} U_1\\& U_1 \end{pmatrix}}_{I \otimes U_1}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} I\\& U_1^\dagger U_2 \end{pmatrix}}_{I\oplus (U_1^\dagger U_2)}
$$